# Color batch error output in different color

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, colors

Is it possible to run a command, for example `xcopy` and have it's standard output and error output in different colors?

I'd prefer using just what comes with Windows 10 without extra downloads. cmd or powershell are okay.

I'd rather not to split outputs to different files and color them separately so that I can see what error applies to what file.

Sample xcopy command:

```
xcopy /y /d /u /c /f c:\dir1\*.exe c:\dir2\dir2\
```

Sample output (** indicates different color)

```
C:\dir\file1.exe
**Sharing violation**
c:\dir\file2.exe
1 file copied
```

I've looked at other answers with colors and they seem to involve manual color management. Set color, output text, set another color. I don't think I can use this approach.

Thanks.

Comment: If you search SU for "batch color", "batch colour", "powershell color" or "powershell colour", there are a lot of questions already answered on the same topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch file change color of specific part of text](https://superuser.com/questions/749561/batch-file-change-color-of-specific-part-of-text)

Comment: Other answers rely on manual color management. Set color, output, set another color. I don't control xcopy's error output

Comment: using `cmd` and wildcards with `xcopy`, no. Even if you use `xcopy` within powershell, no. Use a `for` loop to `xcopy` each file separately, catch the output with another `for` loop (and `2>&1`) and color it according to the errorlevel.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. One of the flags I use is /u which means "Copies files from Source that exist on Destination only". So I don't know list of files in advance. Hmmm maybe I can still enumerate files in source, copy 1 by 1 and use /u flag...